# What mouse controls are available in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, mouse

I've added [`[MOUSE:YES]` to my init.txt](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Technical_tricks#Mouse) to enable mouse control, but I haven't been able to find any info on exactly what mouse controls are available.  So far, the only one I've found is changing the font size via the scroll wheel.

What other mouse forms of mouse control does this enable?  I had expected to be able to use the mouse for selection of tiles in the game map (essentially, as a replacement for the yellow `X` cursor) and perhaps to be able to scroll the map and select commands as well, but none of this seems to work.  (Or I don't understand how to do it.)

Is there additional configuration I need to enable more complete mouse control?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is, in general, very little mouse control in DF. I consider myself a highly efficient DF player, and rarely use the mouse at all. Most [<kbd>d</kbd>esignations](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Designations), such as digging, channeling, stairs, etc., can be drawn free-hand with the mouse, or in rectangles using the keyboard.

Certain screens are mouse-interactive too: The <kbd>d</kbd>esignations list, as well as cursor (IE, you can select **Mine** or **Channel** with the mouse.) You can use the mouse to select items on the <kbd>m</kbd>ilitary screen. You can use the mouse to define burro<kbd>w</kbd>s in the same manner you draw designations.

If you're just looking to increase your DF proficiency, be sure to check out [macros](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Macros_and_Keymaps) and [Quickfort](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Utilities#Quickfort), and to remap any keys which are awkwardly placed for on your keyboard (especially crucial for playing on a laptop's not-full-sized keyboard.) Also, I  wouldn't consider playing without [Dwarf Therapist](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Utilities#Dwarf_Therapist) as well.

Comment: Also right-clicking can move the cursor during designations.

Comment: Not sure how I missed mouse designations.  A real shame that it's freehand rather than rectangular, though.

Comment: It's freehand so that you can draw shapes and select single squares. If you want rectangles, you can use the keyboard to set a start corner, reposition, then select an end corner.

Comment: Also, you can only use the mouse in the default window's size. If you manually drag it bigger, the mouse will only work in the upper-left corner.

Comment: @Ullallulloo - I just confirmed this is not the case. I'm playing with the (slightly outdated) 0.31.23, but I'm fairly certain mouse controls haven't changed since the DF2010 release.

Comment: @DanielRasmussen: hmm, it seems that you're right, but I know that just a little while ago, you couldn't...

Comment: @Ullallulloo it's still there, if you zoom out enough (so that a lot of tiles are visible) part of the screen will stop responding to mouse commands.